# Search in TextEdit Control Devexpress vb.net

Tags: vb.net, search, devexpress, gridcontrol, textedit

There are two controls in my form GridControl and TextEdit Control. I have bulk data of Product names. I need to write 15 to 20 product names in single TextEdit control separating them by spaces. When I type in TextEdit first product name It can find correctly first product name​ in GridControl by `GridView1.ApplyFindFilter("SomeProductName")`. But when I type second Product name it includes previous Product Name in query but I need the previous product name automatically remove from query by pressing space key but not from TextEdit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this to search only on the last term:

```
Public Sub ApplyFindFilterToLastTerm(terms As String)
    Dim lastTerm = terms.Split(" "c).Last
    ApplyFindFilter(lastTerm)
End Sub
```

And call that each time the user enters a space by handling the `KeyDown` event

Comment: When I type a product in the center of Products it searches last product only.